# Vagrant synced_folder not working with docker provider build_dir (Windows)

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I don't succeed providing a dockerfile via Vagrant on Windows. If I use an image (e.g. `d.image = "phusion/baseimage"` instead of `build_dir` everything is fine - but when building from a dockerfile (as shown in the vagrantfile below) - I get the following error (of course I have a `Dockerfile` in `infrastructure/ssh-docker`!):

```
PS C:\privat\cloud-backup\cloud-backup-for-podio> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'app' up with 'docker' provider...
==> app: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    app: Docker host VM is already ready.
==> app: Syncing folders to the host VM...
    app: Preparing SMB shared folders...
    app: Mounting SMB shared folders...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/choose_addressable_ip_addr.rb:7:in `block
 in choose_addressable_ip_addr': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/choose_addressable_ip_addr.rb:6:in `tap'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/choose_addressable_ip_addr.rb:6:in `choose_addressable_ip_addr'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
        ...
```

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config

  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'tcuser'
  config.ssh.port = 22

  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    app.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "smb", smb_host: "MY_IP", smb_username: "WINUSER@DOMAIN", smb_password: "WINPASSWORD"
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      #d.image = "phusion/baseimage"
      d.build_dir = "infrastructure/ssh-docker"
      d.name = "app"
      d.remains_running = true
    end
  end

end
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

ENV HOME /root

# enable ssh
RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down

# Regenerate SSH host keys. baseimage-docker does not contain any, so you
# have to do that yourself. You may also comment out this instruction; the
# init system will auto-generate one during boot.
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server wget lsb-release sudo

EXPOSE 22

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd

# Create and configure vagrant user
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash vagrant
WORKDIR /home/vagrant

# Configure SSH access
RUN mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA6NF8iallvQVp22WDkTkyrtvp9eWW6A8YVr+kz4TjGYe7gHzIw+niNltGEFHzD8+v1I2YJ6oXevct1YeS0o9HZyN1Q9qgCgzUFtdOKLv6IedplqoPkcmF0aYet2PkEDo3MlTBckFXPITAMzF8dJSIFo9D8HfdOV0IAdx4O7PtixWKn5y2hMNG0zQPyUecp4pzC6kivAIhyfHilFR61RGL+GPXQ2MWZWFYbAGjyiYJnAmCP3NOTd0jMZEnDkbUvxhMmBYSdETk1rRgm+R4LOzFUGaHqHDLKLX+FIPKcF96hrucXzcWyLbIbEgE98OHlnVYCzRdK8jlqm8tehUc9c9WhQ== vagrant insecure public key" > /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown -R vagrant: /home/vagrant/.ssh
RUN echo -n 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd

# Enable passwordless sudo for the "vagrant" user
RUN mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d
RUN install -b -m 0440 /dev/null /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
RUN echo 'vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Vagrant version: 1.7.4

Anyone has some idea?

(What I need to do is run a docker image from a dockerfile and have a shared/synced directory..)

Comment: can you try with `d.image = "phusion/baseimage:0.9.17"`

Comment: @FredericHenri with `phusion/baseimage` everything works fine - the problem is with the dockerfile - or am I missing some point?

Comment: oops you're right, misunderstood the question - can you post your docker file ?

Comment: @FredericHenri - I added the docker file above - it basically is taken from https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: hum I've been focused on the docker provision, but it looks the error is due to `app.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "smb", smb_host: "MY_IP", smb_username: "WINUSER@DOMAIN", smb_password: "WINPASSWORD"` can you just try with default sync folder mechanism ? also does it really work with docker image but the same sync folder ?

Comment: Yes - this is my guess too. 
Default sync folder mechanism: Uses "smb" anyways - but without the "smb_host" it fails.
Docker image: Yes - this works - which is why I cannot accept synced_folder is not working with docker file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89395/discussion-between-daniel-sc-and-frederic-henri).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your ip in for smb service

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/github-api", type: 'smb', smb_host: "192.168.1.100"

Comment: This is exactly what I do - see the Vagrantfile in the question. Any other idea?